# Why is there no .traineddata file in eng

Tags: tesseract, tess-two

The question is as the title suggests: Why is there no eng.traineddata file in the folder eng?

I downloaded all the languages as a zip(I did not see any other option) from [here](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/langdata) and unzipped langdata-master.zip. From there, I navigated to the eng folder, but it did not contain the eng.traineddata file that many people were suggesting there should have been. Is there some download I am missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trained data files are available in the [tessdata](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata) project and not in the langdata project you looked in.

The langdata project contains the source training data that was used to create the trained data files. It's useful for people who want to make changes and build their own trained data files.